# Erro na inversão de uma string

Tags: c, string

Estou tentando inverter um *string* através de uma função só que ela está dando erro,porém não sei onde está errado.

Logo abaixo está o meu código.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

 char troca(char nome[100], char nome1[100]);

 int main(void)
{
   char nome[100];
   printf("Informe o nome para ser invertida :");
   scanf("%s", nome);
   printf("%s\n", troca(nome));
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}

char troca(char nome[100], char nome1[100])
  {
    int c = 0, i;
    for(i = strlen(nome) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      nome[c] = nome[i];
      c++;
    }
    nome1[c] = '\0';
    return nome1[c];
  }
```

Comment: Não deveria ser nome1[c] = nome[i]; em vez de nome[c] = nome[i];

Comment: e return nome1;

Comment: e deveria ser "char* troca(" em vez de "char troca("

Comment: troca tem dois parametros e você só está passando 1

Comment: e string.h não está sendo usado

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Tem vários erros aí:

- Não está passando o segundo argumento, na verdade o parâmetro não é necessário
- Não está retornando algo útil pela utilização
- Não está aceitando espaços na entrada de dados
- Algumas erros apareceriam se uma parte desses erros fossem corrigidos.

Assim fica melhor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *troca(char nome[100]) {
    for (int i = 0, j = strlen(nome) - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        char temp = nome[i];
        nome[i] = nome[j];
        nome[j] = temp;
    }
    return nome;
}
  
int main(void) {
   char nome[100];
   printf("Informe o nome para ser invertida :");
   scanf("%[^\n]s", nome);
   printf("%s\n", troca(nome));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GPBJ5j). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wbtadhvj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Invert.c).